# IBM i NetServer : auditing changes to network shares

Tags: ibm-midrange, audit

I would like to audit changes to IBM i network shares, but, despite going through the detailed QAUDJRN entry lists (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzarl/rzarlsecaudje.htm), plus considerable googling, I can't find any reference to these actions being auditable.
I find this quite surprising, so I suspect I have missed something.
Does anyone have any ideas, please (happy to use APIs etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to these shares are logged in AUDJRN as Code T 'Audit trail entry' , Type CD 'Command String'. For example below is a change I made to one via Ops Nav which appears to get converted to a CHGAUT command under the covers.

```
                         Display Journal Entry
```

Object . . . . . . . :                   Library  . . . . . . :
 Member . . . . . . . :
 Incomplete data  . . :   No              Minimized entry data :   *NONE
 Sequence . . . . . . :   31536911
 Code . . . . . . . . :   T  - Audit trail entry
 Type . . . . . . . . :   CD - Command string

```
         Entry specific data
```

Column      *...+....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5
 00001      'CCHGAUT    QSYS      *CMD    ECHGAUT OBJ('/Halcyon'
 00051      '/HALJDE1') USER(*PUBLIC) DTAAUT(*RWX) OBJAUT(*OBJM'
 00101      'GT *OBJEXIST *OBJALTER *OBJREF)'

Journal  . . . . . . :   QAUDJRN         Library  . . . . . . :   QSYS

Sequence . . . . . . :   31536911
Code . . . . . . . . :   T  - Audit trail entry
Type . . . . . . . . :   CD - Command string

Object . . . . . . . :
  Type . . . . . . . :
Date . . . . . . . . :   01/05/18
Time . . . . . . . . :   17:05:01
Flag . . . . . . . . :   0
Count/RRN  . . . . . :   0
Commit cycle ID  . . :   0
Nested commit level  :   0
Job  . . . . . . . . :   820281/QUSER/QZRCSRVS
User profile . . . . :   QSECOFR
Ignore APY/RMV . . . :   No
Ref constraint . . . :   No

Journal  . . . . . . :   QAUDJRN         Library  . . . . . . :   QSYS

Sequence . . . . . . :   31536911
Code . . . . . . . . :   T  - Audit trail entry
Type . . . . . . . . :   CD - Command string

Trigger  . . . . . . :   No
Program  . . . . . . :   QZRCSRVS
  Library  . . . . . :     QSYS
  ASP device . . . . :     *SYSBAS
System sequence  . . :   11592946954968838145
Thread identifier  . :   0000000000000531
Receiver . . . . . . :   AUDRCV1718
  Library  . . . . . :     QGPL
  ASP device . . . . :     *SYSBAS
Journal identifier . :   X'00000000000000000000'
Remote address . . . :   10.72.49.156
Address family . . . :   IPv4

Journal  . . . . . . :   QAUDJRN         Library  . . . . . . :   QSYS

Sequence . . . . . . :   31536911
Code . . . . . . . . :   T  - Audit trail entry
Type . . . . . . . . :   CD - Command string

Remote port  . . . . :   30595
System name  . . . . :   HAL720P6
Arm number . . . . . :   2
Logical unit of work :   *OMITTED
Transaction ID . . . :   *OMITTED

*NOTE* this example is from a partition running V7R1.

Ash.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks v much.

Comment: P.S. which version are you on, Ash? Should have said, mine is V7R2.

Comment: The only place this is documented, btw, seems to be here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaki/rzakijournalfinderall2.htm - none of the other relevant pages seem to list code T against type CD ... very strange. And the description on the link I've just given is 'A change was made to a command string'. (Incidentally same in V7R2 and V7R3 documentation.)

Comment: This is running on V7R1

Comment: Documentation re this (or lack of it) is the same on V7R1, V7R2, V7R3. All very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get access to a (V7R3) test partition this afternoon & have done some experimenting. Unfortunately I just couldn't get Ash's solution to work - whatever I did, no audit journal entries. However I did find a solution of sorts, which is to journal the IFS directory where IBM stashes the share list. This appears to work OK, although one would obviously have to switch this journalling off and on again when applying PTFs or when upgrading. Here's the command I used.

```
STRJRN OBJ(('/QIBM/UserData/OS400/NetServer'))
         JRN('/qsys.lib/tools.lib/netserver.jrn') SUBTREE(*ALL)
```

All in all this is really not the greatest corner of IBM i, unless I am missing something major.

Answer (score 0):

This difference between the two efforts is the system AUDIT journal.  Start at the AUDIT journal to identify what needs to be captured by the AUDIT journal for your particular situation.

Comment: Do you mean you need a specific audit journal option set to get Ash's solution to work? I am sure that is true, I will have another go next time I have access to an IBM i partition I can play with this on. If that's not what you meant, please clarify.